# AVAssetWriter giving bluish video file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avassetwriter

I am recoding a video from my app's screen using the AVAssetWriter class.
Video records. but the recoded video is bluish one.
my code to set up the AVAssetWriter is below

```
-(BOOL) setUpWriter {
    NSError* error = nil;
    videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[self tempFileURL] fileType:AVFileTypeAppleM4V error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    //Configure video
    NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                           nil ];

    CGSize size=[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                                   nil];

    videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    NSDictionary* bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

    avAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes] retain];

    //add input
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];

    return YES;
}
```

Is there any bugs in my code.
How can I solve this problem

Comment: Hi, I tried this code of yours but I am having a problem that I can't understand. My videoWriter finishes successfully but can't find the file on the outputURL. Please help me. and what does avAdaptor do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AVAssetWriterInput is expecting ARGB but you're probably supplying it with RGBA.

That would see the probable 100% alpha interpreted as blue and the red component discarded, which would explain your bluish tint.

Hard to tell without seeing your screen recording code.

Comment: Ya I think so, I'm suplying image from an openglview(of cocos2d scene)
It's RGBA. Where I can change ARGB to RGBA

Comment: I've changed
'NSDictionary* bufferAttributes=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,nil];'
to 
'NSDictionary* bufferAttributes=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,nil];'
It crashes at
'CFDataGetBytes(image,CFRangeMake(0,CFDataGetLength(image)), destPixels);'

Comment: It's not that simple - for RGB iOS AVFoundation prefers kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, so you're going to have to swap the pixel components before writing. If you're using OpenGLES2 you can use the GPU to 'swizzle' the components efficiently. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771471/converting-rgba-to-argb-glreadpixels-avassetwriter

Comment: got solution, just converted ARGB image to RGBA image. I got the idea from purple girl http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/10974345146/mini-tutorial-how-to-capture-video-of-iphone-app-in

Answer (score 3):

probably the problem is in incorrect pixel format, try to use kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA